# Creates a text on a site and retrieves it? c#

Tags: c#, file

I would like to know if there is a text editor or a file uploader/downloader (like pastebin or mega) but for C# program

I explain myself: I am making a program for my college, I would like that when everyone opens my program, that everyone is the same text file, that it can be modified and then saved and when the others load it, there will be the modifications on it

I don't know if it's very clear, but I'd like not to go through servers because I don't understand anything about them

Will there be a solution?

Thank you.

Comment: github: https://github.com

Comment: This might help with future posts: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

That's what [Git](https://git-scm.com/) does... You will need to manage versions of the same file, you will also need to merge file versions and resolve version conflicts.

You can either find a [C# wrapper for git](https://www.google.com/search?q=C%23%20wrapper%20for%20git) or go through the git white paper and do something similar.